# Where can I purchase small scale high res raster imagery?

Tags: raster, data, united-states, download

I am doing a personal project in my neighborhood that requires some georeferencing and as such I am looking for some sub-1m accuracy orthos with which to assist. The normal free sources such as USGS do not offer this level of accuracy.

I am aware that I can also ask my municipality (city or county) to clip me a piece of imagery as they usually have more accurate orthos than what is available publicly, but I am wondering if there is a commercial off-the-shelf solution that allows you to specify a small area to clip and pay some nominal fee (~$100) for imagery.

Comment: FOI request for the relevant imagery?

Comment: "_I am aware that I can also ask my municipality_" - did you ask them?  What did they say?  When I worked for a city this was a regular request we never had any issue completing, I wonder why you seem to rather pay for imagery than obtain it easily from your city?

Comment: Not every municipality is as responsive as you. I've already reached out to my municipality multiple times trying to get imagery and received no response. Sometimes I'd rather pay a minimal sum over being forced to deal with bureaucracy.

Comment: Also, not every municipality has up-to-date high res imagery. I also used to work for a city and we would not update our highest resolution imagery more often than every 5 years for cost-saving purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Sanborn has an online image purchase portal at: https://online.sanborn.com/

Maybe they have coverage in your area with suffucient rexooution.

(Note that I am not affiliated with Sanborn and do not receive any benefit from this recommendation...except possibly SE reputation points!)